# Simple psql count query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am very new to postgresql and would like to generate some summary data from our table

We have a simple message board - table name `messages` which has an element `ctg_uid`. Each `ctg_uid` corresponds to a category name in the table `categories`.

Here are the categories `select * from categories ORDER by ctg_uid ASC;`

```
 ctg_uid |    ctg_category    | ctg_creator_uid 
---------+--------------------+-----------------
       1 | general            |               1
       2 | faults             |               1
       3 | computing          |               1
       4 | teaching           |               2
       5 | QIS-FEEDBACK       |               3
       6 | QIS-PHYS-FEEDBACK  |               3
       7 | SOP-?-CHANGE       |               3
       8 | agenda items       |               7
      10 | Acq & Process      |               2
      12 | physics-jobs       |               3
      13 | Tech meeting items |              12
      16 | incident-forms     |               3
      17 | ERRORS             |               3
      19 | Files              |              10
      21 | QIS-CAR            |               3
      22 | doses              |               4
      24 | admin              |               3
      25 | audit              |               3
      26 | For Sale           |               4
      31 | URGENT-REPORTS     |               4
      34 | dt-jobs            |               3
      35 | JOBS               |               3
      36 | IN-PATIENTS        |               4
      37 | Ordering           |               4
      38 | dep-meetings       |               4
      39 | reporting          |               4
```

What I would like to do is for all messages on our `messages` is count the frequency of each category

I can do it on a category by category basis
`SELECT count(msg_ctg_uid) FROM messages where msg_ctg_uid='13';`

However is it possible to do this in a one liner?

The following gives the the category and ctg_uid for each message
`SELECT ctg_category, msg_ctg_uid FROM messages INNER JOIN categories ON (ctg_uid = msg_ctg_uid);`

but `SELECT ctg_category, count(msg_ctg_uid) FROM messages INNER JOIN categories ON (ctg_uid = msg_ctg_uid);`

gives me the error `ERROR:  column "categories.ctg_category" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`

How do I aggregate the frequency of each category ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the group by clause:

```
SELECT ctg_category, count(msg_ctg_uid) 
FROM messages INNER JOIN categories ON (ctg_uid = msg_ctg_uid);
GROUP BY ctg_category
```

this means you want the count per `ctg_category`